# Screen printing a glowing effect on a black garment

Tags: screen-printing, halftone

My goal is to screen print a "glowing sign" on a black garment, such as the one below:

[image]

There's a main color and a brighter, accent color. The main color also has the fading background effect.

The idea is get something like this onto the garment:
[image]

I created halftones like below:

[image]

As shown the purple base layer also extends a shadow using halftones. For the solid parts I made a white underbase and choked it, but I'm not sure whether I should also put a white underbase on the halftoned sections.

How can I best achieve this glow effect on a black garment?
Should I put an underbase for the halftones even if it's too fine to choke it?

Also, I'm planning to print this on a 230 mesh screen for the purple and 156 mesh for the underbase. How do I know if my halftone dots are too small for the mesh?

The film positive for this came out like so:

[image]

I haven't tried burning a screen with this film yet, but I'm worried that I've already done something wrong!

Any additional tips and advise for this design welcome.

Comment: I work with offset print and don't have much experience with screen printing on garment. Looking forward to seeing answers to this. Just have some questions: You talk about "halftone dots". I only see *lines*, is it just the images? And I see that your screen pattern is at zero angle. Wouldn't it make more sense to turn it 45 degrees so it doesn't follow the mesh?

Comment: As for the size of your halftone dots, there's a formula I've come across that says: Dot Size x 4.5 = Mesh Count. There's [a link here](https://www.atlasscreensupply.com/blog/choosing-the-right-mesh-and-halftone-dot.htm) with more info. I have to be honest I don't think that underprinting the halftone dot pattern in white sounds practical. Unless there is exact registration between each pass, then you are going to have problems. There are too many potential pitfalls here. I think you should probably experiment on a piece of black cloth before printing the garment.

Comment: One possible solution is perhaps not to rely on white underprinting at all, and perhaps try to use opaque screen printing ink instead. Again I'd suggest you experiment on a piece of cloth to see if the result will be good enough.

Comment: At the end of [this slightly related answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/140885/84899) I show the problem in fading white underprint when using opaque inks.

Comment: @Wolff - yeah that's exactly what I imagined would be a problem.